# socket.io: Is is possible to intercept a join namespace request?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

My Node.js knowledge is fairly basic. I'm using socket.io to create a server and socket.io-client-swift in an iOS app.

I would like the server to create a dynamic namespace depending on the users selection on the client app. The idea being that all users with a specific selection join the same namespace on the server. This allows messages to be broadcast to all of those users within the namespace.

The problem is that the socket.io documentation and code appears to assume that you will be hardcoding the namespace name in the node.js code and that the namespace will be defined before the client iOS code attempts to join it.

Here's what i would like to occur:

1. Client requests to join a namespace called 'abc'.
2. Server receives request.
3. Something on the server checks the request, figures out there is no current namespace for 'abc' and dynamically allocates one.
4. Server finishes processing the join request, connecting the socket to the newly created namespace.

It's step #3 that I'm having problems with. I've tried using `io.use(function(socket, next){...}` to intercept the incoming request, but it appears that occurs after the server has determined whether there is a matching namespace for the request.

Does anyone have any idea how to intercept an incoming namespace request?

Comment: Why do you think that a server has to "dynamically allocate" a namespace?  That part has me confused.  A client just connects to a socket.io namespace path.  The server didn't have to create anything before that happened.

Comment: Yes it does. If you don't declare a namespace using `io.use{...}` in the server, then the server just ignores the namespace.

Comment: Please show me how `io.use()` "declares a namespace".  I still don't understand what you're talking about.  I know you can listen for specific incoming namespace connections.  Is that what you're trying to do - to listen for all namespace connections regardless of the namespace?

Comment: Sorry my bad. `io.of(...)` creates a namespace. `io.use(...)` adds an interceptor. What I need to do is intercept an incoming request before it's directed to a namespace. Then I can create the namespace for the request if it doesn't currently exist. Interceptors created with `io.use(...)` are called after the namespace has been found. I need to do it before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out. I added some code to my server.js like this:

```
// Lets Swizzle in some wrapper code.
//var originalConnection = Client.prototype.connect;
Client.prototype.originalConnect = Client.prototype.connect;
Client.prototype.connect = function(name){
    var nsp = io.nsps[name];
    if (!nsp) {
        io.of(name);
    }
    this.originalConnect(name);
};
```

Effectively I swizzled in a wrapper function that does the dynamic namespace creation.